# All CollectionViewCell height equal to largest cell label dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift5

I need to create a vertical CollectionView which have a dynamic label and all CollectionViewCell height should be same to the largest cell content. How to calculate largest cell height and assign that height to every cell?
I have tried many solution but none is working for me.
Any solution pls

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already, how does your data look? It would be helpful if you could post some code. Nevertheless the most simple approach would be to calculate the height for all cells manually and then select the highest value out of them.

Answer (score 2):

Start by adding the following UILabel Extension (add anywhere outside of the ViewController):

```
extension UILabel{
    public var getHeight: CGFloat {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text
        label.attributedText = attributedText
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }
}
```

Then you can calculate the height for each label while the collection view cell is rendering. In the following, I check to see if the new height is greater then the last tallest height - this is saved to my variable called `tallestCellHeight`. Use this variable to set the height of the cell.

```
var tallestCellHeight: CGFloat = 0
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! testCell
    
    cell.testLabel.text = messages[indexPath.row]
    
    let currentCellHeight = cell.testLabel.getHeight
    if currentCellHeight > tallestCellHeight {
        tallestCellHeight = currentCellHeight
        print(tallestCellHeight)
    }
    
    cell.backgroundColor = .tertiarySystemFill
    
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    CGSize(width: 150, height: tallestCellHeight)
}
```

After the collection view has rendered, I will have the tallest cell height saved to the variable `tallestCellHeight`.

Lastly, reload the collection view on the main thread in `viewDidLoad()`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Don't forget to include `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

**Entire Code**

```
import UIKit

let messages: [String] = ["hello and welcome", "this is a really cool app", "this is awesome", "welcome to the test for my new application", "hello everyone"]

class testCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    var tallestCellHeight: CGFloat = 0
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! testCell
        
        cell.testLabel.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        
        let currentCellHeight = cell.testLabel.getHeight
        if currentCellHeight > tallestCellHeight {
            tallestCellHeight = currentCellHeight
            print(tallestCellHeight)
        }
        
        cell.backgroundColor = .tertiarySystemFill
        
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 150, height: tallestCellHeight)
    }
}

extension UILabel{
    public var getHeight: CGFloat {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text
        label.attributedText = attributedText
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }
}
```

Comment: getHeight function not returning proper height of label.

Comment: How are you applying it? To call it, use `cell.testLabel.getHeight` and it should return the height of the label as a CGFloat. I have applied this method and tested it, and it should work for any label. Do you perhaps have any margins or padding added to your UILabel?